# Looping through a set of sequences satisfying a certain property, without storing them

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, recursion

Below is a MATLAB code (recursion) which inputs a vector `(l_1,l_2,...,l_r)` of non negative integers and an integer `m` prints all sequences `(m_1,m_2,...,m_r)` satisfying:

`0 <= m_i <= l_i` for all `1 <= i <= r` and `m_1 + m_2 + ... + m_r = m`

The `r` is captured in the function definition by calling the size of the `(l_i)` array below:

```
function arr=sumseq(m,lims)
    arr=[];
    r=size(lims,2);
    if r==0 || m<0
        arr=[];
    elseif r==1 && lims(1)>=m
        arr=[m]; %#ok<NBRAK>
    else
        for i=0:lims(1)
            if(lims(1)<0)
                arr=[];
            else
                v=sumseq(m-i,lims(2:end));
                arr=[arr;[i*ones(size(v,1),1) v]];
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Here what I have done is, stored a whole array of them and made it my output. Instead I want to only print them one by one and not store them in an array. This seems simple enough as there is not much choice in which line(s) I need to change (I believe it is the contents of the `else` block inside the `for` loop), but I get into a fix every time I try to achieve it.

(Also, MATLAB warned me that if I kept re-initializing the array with a larger array like in the statement:

```
arr=[arr;[i*ones(size(v,1),1) v]];
```

it reallocates a fresh array for all the contents of `arr` and spends a 'lot' of time doing so.)

In short: recursion or not, I want to save the trouble of storing it, and need an algorithm which is as efficient as or more efficient than what I have here.

Comment: You’re silencing this warning: `arr=[m]; %#ok<NBRAK>`. Instead, pay attention to it and remove the meaningless brackets, they don’t do anything. The square brackets are for concatenation, but you have only one value inside, there’s noting to concatenate.

Comment: As per your question, “but I get into a fix every time I try to achieve it.” How so? What did you try? Did `disp` not show the array properly? What is the difficulty?